# What's wrong with my Treetop grammar?

Tags: ruby, parsing, grammar, treetop

I have the grammar file `alexa_scrape.tt`:

```
grammar AlexaScrape
  rule document
    category_listing*
  end
  rule category_listing
    category_line url_line*
  end
  rule category_line
    category "\n"
  end
  rule category
    ("/" [^/]+)+
  end
  rule url_line
    [0-9]+ ". " url "\n"
  end
  rule url
    [^\n]*
  end
end
```

I have a ruby file which attempts to make use of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -I .
require 'rubygems'
require 'polyglot'
require 'treetop'
require 'alexa_scrape.tt'

parser = AlexaScrapeParser.new
p( parser.parse("") || parser.failure_reason )
p( parser.parse("/x\n") || parser.failure_reason )
```

But I'm not getting the results I expected:

```
SyntaxNode offset=0, ""
"Expected one of /, \n at line 2, column 1 (byte 4) after /x\n"
```

It parses the empty string properly (as the trivial match for `document`, zero `category_listing`s), but fails to parse `"/x\n"` (as the document containing a single `category_listing` that itself has zero `url_line`s).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the regex in `category` is advancing through the white space needed to match `category_line` ... do this:

```
  rule category
    ("/" [^/\s]+)+    # or perhaps ("/" [^/\n]+)+
  end
```

(And, wow, *a Treetop question.* This is number 47 in the history of SO and its 4 million total questions. One in 87,000 SO questions are tagged *Treetop)*.

Comment: [#48](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655658/can-i-use-treetop-to-parse-an-io) now available.